# How to replace a text if it was interrupted by a line break or a tag?

Tags: regex, powershell

I read a file from a program with powershell and want to replace certain strings there. For example, the content of a file looks like this:

```
<"#319",
    @"Sprache" =        "DE">

<F5@T@Z7@L1031>5<F5@T@Z7@L1033>)<F5@Z7@L1031><Tab>#319-10002
```

Now I want to replace e.g. `#319-10002` by `Some Text`, which is no problem.

```bsh
$output = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter (Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath "$outputName.ildoc")

Get-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $inputPath -ChildPath "$inputName.ildoc") -ReadCount 512 | ForEach-Object {
    $value = $_

    foreach($entry in $csvInput.GetEnumerator()) {
        $value = $value -replace $entry.Name, $entry.Value
    }

    $output.Write((($value | Out-String) -replace "`r`n", "`n"))
}

$output.Close()
```

Those "variables" are from a CSV file and are therefore dynamic. There are 2 types:

1. #Number-Number
2. #Number-Text

Now there is also the case that the line is longer than 80 characters. Then the program that generated the file automatically inserts a line break after 80 characters.

```
<"#319",
    @"Sprache" =        "DE">

<F5@T@Z1@L1031>3<F5@T@Z1@L1033>)<F5@Z1@L127><Tab><F5@Z1@L1031>Some more Text #3
19-10002
```

Then there is also the case that the string is interrupted by tags. If text is in tables and the text is longer than the column, the program automatically inserts a `<SR>` followed by a line break at the place of the break.

```
<Cell, Straddle = 2,
    Top Ruling Color =  16,
    Left Ruling Weight =    0.75,
    Left Ruling Color = 30,
    Left Ruling Visible =   no><!Page,
    Left Margin =       0.0039372 Inches,
    Right Margin =      0.0039372 Inches>
<"text:zentr">

#319-10<SR>
002
```

I am currently quite at a loss how to solve the problem. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: The sample looks like a markup language. Do you know what it is, maybe there's already a parser for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. The only thing I can say is that it is a .ildoc file (Interleaf document) used by the software Interleaf or Quicksilver.

Comment: I wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What's the reason for string replacing? Maybe Broadvision (Interleaf is no more, Broadvision acquired it in the 2000) can supply a tool or API for file editing instead?

Comment: The reason is that we get translations from a client and need to replace the placeholders so that we can automatically update the documents when changes are made. I've contacted Broadvision, but I don't think there's an API, library or tool for that.

Comment: Should the extra inserted line breaks and `<SR>` + Linebreak be kept in the replaced file, or is it possible to remove them even though some lines may then become longer than 80 characters?

Comment: @Theo the <SR> and Linebreak can be replaced and it's no problem if the line gets longer than 80 characters.

Comment: @vonPryz I got a feedback from Broadvision. They have a very old SDK for Lisp, which I could buy. That would probably the best way to modify the files, but I have no idea how to work with lisp and need to learn the SDK. That's to much effort, for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before applying your replacements you could preprocess the file
to remove the Pos~80 and `<SR>` breaks with Regular Expressions:

```
(Get-Content .\input.ildoc -raw) -replace '(?m)(?<=^.{79,})\r?\n' -replace '\<SR\>\r?\n'
```

yiedls here (with both above samples)

```
<"#319",
    @"Sprache" =        "DE">

<F5@T@Z1@L1031>3<F5@T@Z1@L1033>)<F5@Z1@L127><Tab><F5@Z1@L1031>Some more Text #319-10002
<Cell, Straddle = 2,
    Top Ruling Color =  16,
    Left Ruling Weight =    0.75,
    Left Ruling Color = 30,
    Left Ruling Visible =   no><!Page,
    Left Margin =       0.0039372 Inches,
    Right Margin =      0.0039372 Inches>
<"text:zentr">

#319-10002
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tackle this using some cleaning up regexes on the file content first.

Perhaps this could help:

**First pass** to deal with #Number-Number or #Number-Text broken by line breaks

```
$content = $content -replace '(#)(?:\r?\n)*(\d+)(?:\r?\n)*([-\w]+)', '$1$2$3'
```

this changes

```
<F5@T@Z1@L1031>3<F5@T@Z1@L1033>)<F5@Z1@L127><Tab><F5@Z1@L1031>Some more Text #3
19-10002


<F5@T@Z1@L1031>3<F5@T@Z1@L1033>)<F5@Z1@L127><Tab><F5@Z1@L1031>Some more Text #3
20-TEXT
```

into

```
<F5@T@Z1@L1031>3<F5@T@Z1@L1033>)<F5@Z1@L127><Tab><F5@Z1@L1031>Some more Text #319-10002

<F5@T@Z1@L1031>3<F5@T@Z1@L1033>)<F5@Z1@L127><Tab><F5@Z1@L1031>Some more Text #320-TEXT
```

**Second pass** deals with `<SR>` followed by newlines:

```
$content = $content -replace '(#[-\d]+)<SR>\r?\n([-\w]+)', '$1$2'
```

this changes stuff like

```
#319-10<SR>
002
```

into

```
#319-10002
```

After this, the elements to replace should be no longer broken up.

Putting this together, you can try this code:

```
# get the content of the file as a single string including line breaks
$content = Get-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $inputPath -ChildPath "$inputName.ildoc") -Raw

# remove garbage linebreaks
$content = $content -replace '(#)(?:\r?\n)*(\d+)(?:\r?\n)*([-\w]+)', '$1$2$3'
# remove garbage <SR>linebreaks
$content = $content -replace '(#[-\d]+)<SR>\r?\n([-\w]+)', '$1$2'

# split the content into an array of strings and loop through
for ($i = 0; $i -lt ($content -split '\r?\n').Count; $i++) {
    $line = $content[$i]
    foreach($entry in $csvInput.GetEnumerator()) {
        $line = $line -replace $entry.Name, $entry.Value
    }
    # overwrite the string element with the replaced value
    $content[$i] = $line
}

# finally write the updated array as string joined with '\n'
Set-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath "$outputName.ildoc") -Value ($content -join '\n')
```

Comment: IMO the the 79/80 pos break could occur anywhere in a replacement or other string depending on the length of the text before in the line, so focusing on the `#` doesn't make sense.